# Can't open Nvidia settings & NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, purge

I installed the Nvidia drivers succesfully once, then I removed them because I had problems with optimus. But because I need them now to run a couple of programs and games.

Using dpkg -l | grep nvidia:

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                  390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                  390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                      390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                    390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-390                                 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8                               all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Display adapter info

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:160 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
```

Nvidia module info:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.3-041803-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        390.77
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     209B1D0CB123DE466F700AD
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        ipmi_msghandler
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       4.18.3-041803-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UseThreadedInterrupts:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableIBMNPURelaxedOrderingMode:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

So I read this can happen because I didn's purge all Nvidia files off my pc.

Could someone help me remove every single Nvidia file off of my pc, or provide me with another way that I could use to fix this problem?

Thanks!